# ngFor index on nested object

Tags: angular, ngfor

I was trying to make a table for a logical framework and i need to iterate the object so i can have a numbering order of it.

[Heres my sample in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8ngzhl)

I want my result to be like this

```
OUTCOMES
1. (Summary Outcome 1)
2. (Summary Outcome 2)
OUTPUT
1.1. (Summary Output 1.1 for Outcome 1)
1.2. (Summary Output 1.2 for Outcome 1)
2.1 (Summary Output 2.1 for Outcome 2)
```

Scenarios:

- If theres a 2 Output for Outcome #1, Output #2 should have 2.1
- If Outcomes only have 1 Output each, number should be

  OUTPUT

  1. (Summary Output 1 for Outcome 1)
  2. (Summary Output 2 for Outcome 2)

Comment: not very clear. can you  explain more

Comment: Updated my stackblitz

Comment: this is hard to done. can you edit your json (back-end) to send like this. {
                  'summary': 'Summary Output 1.1',
                  'outcome':1
                },]

Comment: 'designSummaries': [] can there more summeries? so do it like this  -> {
              'id' : 3,
              'outcome':1,
              'designSummaries': [
                {
                  'summary': 'Summary Output 1.1',
                },
              ]
            },

Comment: yes it can have more summarie. ok ill try that one thanks :) will update you if it works

Comment: yes let me know after done. i'll help you.

Comment: seems like its the same way as iterating the index

Comment: is there any way to know if previous set of obj or next set of obj to know if theres nested array on it ?

Comment: in your situation, we have to deal with strings not a good way. but if you send outkome as a key value pair, yes. we can map these things to dictionary and get all done.

Comment: can i have some sample snippet of your way dealing with it ?

Comment: it's not a easy task because of your json object is complicated.if u can arrange it like i said ,i can show how to done.because it is time wasting if can't done after.

Comment: there will be only two types `OUTCOMES` and `OUTPUT` right? or you can have more type in future?

Comment: sorry, was kinda confused for a second. I updated my stackblitz :)

Comment: There was for types : `IMPACTS`, `OUTCOMES`, `OUTPUTS` and `ACTIVITIES`. In the example code i only put outcome and output as example

Comment: she if this can help https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bbk1b

Comment: Thanks will check it and will update you later if i get the logic of it :)

Comment: @jitender i updated your code and tested the scenario 2 seems like i need to put some condition for your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o2ht6q

Comment: After you update.i'l help you.It can be done.